# Cloth Simulation - Sleeves keep sliding off arms

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]
I've done a cloth simulation however everything manages to stay on the mesh except the sleeves. Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell without seeing it animated or seeing more settings... however, this is likely an issue with the Collision settings on the model mesh.

Firstly, ensure you have 'Applied Scale' on all of your meshes - this is good practice anyway but if you haven't done this it can cause strange effects with your simulation.

Next check the Collision 'Cloth and Soft Body' settings. Reduce the 'Inner' and try the simulation again (free and re-bake) to see if that helps.

The 'Inner' boundary needs to be less than half the thinnest part of your mesh that's involved in the collision - otherwise the collision bound can "leak" out of the back face of your mesh and upset the collision.

---

After reviewing the uploaded Blend file, the issue was actually just that the Modifier stack was in the incorrect order :

[image: modifier stack for collision]

In the original file the Collision modifier was *above* the Armature modifier. This meant that the collision was working correctly but was on the *unposed* model - which was obviously in a different position to the 'base' model.

Simply swapping the Collision to be *after* the Armature modifier resolves the problem and the collision is on the *posed* mesh.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I've applied scale and played around with 'inner setting' however it doesn't seem to be working. Would I be able to upload my file and you can have a look at it please?

Comment: Sure - upload it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then edit your question and paste the link from blend-exchange into your question.

Comment: Thank you. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/SEdO7ZG1

Comment: The arms originally were lower down so I moved the arms of the body higher up so it’s in line with the sleeves. But I applied all transforms. Could this also be part of the reason?

Comment: Moving them using the armature doesn't actually affect the base mesh. To properly apply them you'd need to click the Apply button of the Armature modifier - although this then makes it unposable unless you re-rig your mesh, so you wouldn't normally do that. Just swapping the modifiers is fine - the Collision would be expected to be the last (or nearly last) one in the stack anyway (since then it works on the final state of the mesh).

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much!